# MediWiki LDAP Cannot bind to LDAP (-1) - Cannot contact LDAPServer

Tags: ldap, mediawiki

I hope someone can help me! I'm trying to configure a MediaWiki with ldap login. I installed the necessary Plugins:

MediaWiki   1.34.1
PHP     7.2.11 (fpm-fcgi)
MariaDB     10.3.17-MariaDB

LDAPAuthentication2 1.0.1
LDAPAuthorization   1.1.0
LDAPProvider    1.0.4
PluggableAuth   5.7

I configured it with this json-File:

```
{
"test.de": {
    "connection": {
        "server": "server.test.de",
        "port" : "389",
        "user": "cn=******,ou=no gpo,ou=spz,ou=usr,ou=auth,dc=test,dc=de",
        "pass": "******",
        "enctype": "clear",
        "options": {
            "LDAP_OPT_DEREF": 1
        },
        "basedn": "DC=test,DC=de",
        "binddn": "DC=test,DC=de",
        "groupbasedn": "DC=test,DC=de",
        "userbasedn": "DC=test,DC=de",
        "searchattribute": "sAMAccountName",
        "searchstring": "TEST\\USER-NAME",
        "usernameattribute": "sAMAccountName",
        "realnameattribute": "cn",
        "emailattribute": "mail"
    },
    "userinfo": [],
    "groupsync": []
}
```

}

My localSettings looks like this:

```
# Berechtingung zum Einloggen über exterene Authentifizierung
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['autocreateaccount'] = true;
# als erstes wird PlugableAuth angebunden
wfLoadExtension( 'PluggableAuth' );
# $wgPluggableAuth_EnableAutoLogin  = true;
# $wgPluggableAuth_EnableLocalLogin     = true;

# LDAPProvider
$LDAPProviderDomainConfigs = "/etc/mediawiki/ldapprovider.json";

wfLoadExtension( 'LDAPProvider' );
wfLoadExtension( 'LDAPAuthorization' );
wfLoadExtension( 'LDAPAuthentication2' );

$LDAPAuthentication2AllowLocalLogin     = true;
# $LDAPAuthentication2UsernameNormalizer    = true;

$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
$wgShowSQLErrors = true;
$wgShowDBErrorBacktrace = true;
```

When i try to connect to LDAP via the maintenace-Tools from LDAPProvider "CheckLogin" and "ShowUserInfo" everything seems to be fine. When i go to the Loginpage of my MediaWiki, the first look is good. There is a login-Form with a Dropdown to choose my Domain or Locallogin. Locallogin works fine. But the login with my Domain credentials gives this Error:

```
[Xw8bEmunzqHDU7iHR4WlBgAAAEk] /mediawiki/index.php?title=Spezial:PluggableAuthLogin MWException from line 168 of /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/LDAPProvider/src/Client.php: Could not bind to LDAP: (-1) Can't contact LDAP server

Backtrace:

#0 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/LDAPProvider/src/Client.php(91): MediaWiki\Extension\LDAPProvider\Client->establishBinding()
#1 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/LDAPProvider/src/Client.php(328): MediaWiki\Extension\LDAPProvider\Client->init()
#2 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/LDAPAuthentication2/src/PluggableAuth.php(81): MediaWiki\Extension\LDAPProvider\Client->canBindAs(string, string)
#3 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/PluggableAuth/includes/PluggableAuthLogin.php(31): MediaWiki\Extension\LDAPAuthentication2\PluggableAuth->authenticate(NULL, string, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(575): PluggableAuthLogin->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(611): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(296): MediaWiki\Special\SpecialPageFactory->executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#7 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(900): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#8 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(527): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/html/mediawiki/index.php(44): MediaWiki->run()
#10 {main}
```

I absolutely have no further idea, what could be wrong and what i could try. I hope there is someone out there, who could help!

Thank you and greetings

Björn

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the file `/etc/mediawiki/ldapprovider.json` is readable by your `fpm-fcgi` process user (like `www-data`).

If this doesn't help, you should check connectivity from your web server. Install `ldap-utils`, then type `ldapsearch -h "server.test.de" -p 389 -D "cn=******,ou=no gpo,ou=spz,ou=usr,ou=auth,dc=test,dc=de" -w "******" -x -v -b "DC=test,DC=de"`. The output may give you some hint on what is wrong. So far, it looks like there is no connection to the LDAP server at all. You could `ping server.test.de` from the command line of your web server.